# Why do the steps in this proof to show that $\theta(e_1)=e_2$ for a group isomorphism make sense?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to understand the steps taken in this proof I saw in my group theory course.

It's a prof of the statement that if;

$\theta:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ is an isomorphism then , $\theta(e_1)=e_2.$ and goes as follows

$\theta(e_1)=\theta(e_1e_1)=\theta(e_1)\theta(e_1)$

Then we multiply through by $[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$

To get

$\theta(e_1)[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}=\theta(e_1)\theta(e_1)[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$

which gives us $e_2=\theta(e_1)$.

I don't really see how it does though as forgetting about groups and identities for a moment and just considering what I know about function and inverses I would have read the line before the statement is proved as

$f(f^{-1}(y))=f(f(f^{-1}(y))$

$f(x)=f(f(x))$

$f(x)=f(y)$

which doesn't really make any sense.
What am I considering incorrectly here ?

Note: an edit was made to this post to fix an error that @Mike noticed

Comment: What is $f$? What is $y$?

Comment: @AlexProvost say $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $x\in X, y\in Y$

Comment: That's not saying anything. What is $f$, precisely, in the context of this question?

Comment: Note that $[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$ is not the same as $\theta^{-1}(e_1)$, which doesn't even make sense. Also, if $X\neq Y$ in your example then $f(f(f^{-1}(y)))$ doesn't make sense either. A set of functions is only a group under composition if they are all bijections from the same set to itself.

Comment: @AlexProvost I'm saying that when I consider an arbitrary function f, then this is how the composition of taking f and its inverse would work, It's just an example of how I thought it should work for the actual proof, but my real question is how can we use $\theta(e_1)[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}=\theta(e_1)\theta(e_1)[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$ to get $\theta(e_1)=e_2$

Comment: @Servaes That must be where my confusion lies because of course it did make no sense when i considered it that way. What exactly does $[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$ mean ?

Comment: @exodius $\theta(e_1)^{-1}$ is, by definition, the unique element in $G_2$ that yields $e_2$ when multiplied with $\theta(e_1)$.

Comment: It is the inverse element of $\theta(e_1)$, where $\theta(e_1)$ is some element of $G_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $e_1$ is the identity element in $G_1$ and $e_2$ the identity element in $G_2$.

Shouldn't it be

$$\theta(e_1) = \theta(e_1e_1) = \theta(e_1)\theta(e_1)$$

(Check to make sure you see that this string of equations is indeed valid)

And then multiplying both sides by $[\theta(e_1)]^{-1}$, the LHS is $e_2$ (because $bb^{-1} = e_2$ for every $b \in G_2$, and $\theta(e_1)$ is indeed in $G_2$). While the RHS is $\theta(e_1)\theta(e_1)[\theta(e_1)]^{-1} =\theta(e_1)$.

This gives $e_2 = \theta(e_1)$, which is what you wanted.

Comment: I just realised where I was going wrong , thanks Mike :) and the rest of you guys too :)